# Automatic template deduction when lhs reference is used

Tags: c++, templates, type-conversion, type-deduction

I was wondering if I write something like this:

```
Type &var = database.get<TYPE>(name);
```

Assuming that `database` is a container able to store datablocks of different datatypes. To get a reference to that datablock, the `name` as `std::string` is passed to get() so that at different places with that call I have a way to access certain 'global' variables. I have get() as a template method and I would like to keep it that way.

What I want to do is shorten that call an elegant way like this:

```
Type &var = database.get(name);
```

So the template deduction is automatically performed. Now I could create a macro for that, but this is not what I want to do, as I do not consider it elegant for such case.

That deduction though does not work, because we need a template parameter. Why can't the compiler take what is set for the variable and pass it as template parameter automatically? Is there a way to do this? I don't want to have any type conversions in this case. Can we omit it?

Comment: Template deduction is done at compile time. Does the compiler know at compile time, what data is stored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't do this---the rules of the language simply don't allow the compiler to take into account the declared type of `var` in order to perform the deduction. (Note that template arguments for a function template **can** be deduced when initializing a function pointer by taking the address of a function template. However, that's not what's happening in this case.)

However, you can easily avoid writing the type twice or inducing any undesirable conversions, by using `auto`:

```
auto& var = database.get<Type>(name);
```

Comment: Yeah, okay, thanks for the explanation. ``auto`` is really a nice alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this is not possible. What you are trying to do is to have the return type of a templated function based on the value of its parameter. 
This cannot work.

Automatic template deduction (like you mentioned) can only be performed, if the template parameter is obvious. For example:

```
template<_T> void func(_T param) { }
```

This can be called like

```
int a; 
func(a); //instead of func<int>(a);
```

here the compiler knows exactly what you are trying to do.

Because all templates are resolved at compile time, there is no way of changig a methods return type based on any vague arguments.

You could have a look at [boost::any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/any.html), which does your Job quite well.